# При аплоде картинки microtime дает разные значения

Tags: php, upload, unixtimestamp

Подскажите нужно сделать имя файла уникальным с помощью microtime и делая

```
     $formatted_filename = str_replace(".", "_", microtime(true)) . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $file = $formatted_filename;
    $config['file_name']    =   $file;
    echo '<pre>$config::'.print_r($config,true).'</pre>';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $data['image']      =   $file;
    echo '<pre>$data::'.print_r($data,true).'</pre>';
```

Вижу что имя файла 2 скопировалось в копирование файла и в  массив для записи в базу $data НО разное
Причем последнее более позднее на какие-то сотые ? А как правильно ? Или есть способ лучше ?

Спасибо!

Comment: Нифига не понял... Попробуйте описать проблему еще раз, но по человечески

Comment: в БД в столбец время сохраняешь? вынеси `microtime` в отдельную переменную и вставляй уже её и туда и сюда